# Ember.Select view complaining about value passed

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

I have an Ember.js (1.0.0) Application for which I am trying to implement the built-in `Ember.Select` view.

This piece of the application shows three lists of tasks: `inProgress`, `completed`, and `unassigned`. The user can filter the tasks shown by their corresponding project. This is where the `Ember.Select` view comes in. However, when I load the route, Ember barks at me about the type of value I am giving it:

`Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed projects.all`

`Uncaught TypeError: Object projects.all has no method 'addArrayObserver'`

`Uncaught Error: Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM.`

I have been wrestling with this for hours, trying different permutations of the code below - and I know I **must** be missing something obvious, because it just *can't* be this difficult to get such a simple component to work properly. Hoping you guys can point me in the right direction.

Here is my Route:

```
Bee.TasksIndexRoute = Bee.Auth.Route.extend
    setupController: (ctrl) ->
        # get tasks
        Bee.Auth.send
            url: Bee.endpoint "/tasks"
        .done (tasks) -> 
            ctrl.set "tasks.all", tasks
        # get projects
        Bee.Auth.send
            url: Bee.endpoint "/projects"
        .done (projects) -> 
            ctrl.set "projects.owned", projects.owned
            ctrl.set "projects.participating", projects.participating
            ctrl.set "projects.all", projects.owned.concat projects.participating
```

Here is my Controller:

```
Bee.TasksIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
    project: null
    content:
        tasks: 
            all: []
            inProgress: []
            completed: []
            unassgined: []
    projects: 
        all: []
        owned: []
        participating: []
    visible: (->
        ctrl = @
        # filter tasks here            
    ).property "project"
```

Here is my Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="tasks/index">
    <div class="center-pane">
        <div class="top_options">
            <div class="project_filter">
                <strong>Viewing: </strong>
                {{view Ember.Select
                   content=projects.all
                   optionValuePath='content._id'
                   optionLabelPath='content.title'
                   value=project
                   prompt='All Tasks'
                }}
            </div>
            <strong class="gold-gradient option_button">
                {{#link-to 'tasks.create' classNames='new_task'}}Create Task{{/link-to}}
            </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
            <div class="col-header in-progress light-gradient">
                <h3>In Progress</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="tasks_active_list">
                {{#if visible.inProgress.length}}
                    <ul>{{#each visible.inProgress}}{{view Bee.TaskListView}}{{/each}}</ul>
                {{else}}
                    <p class="no_projects">None</p>
                {{/if}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
            <div class="col-header completed light-gradient">
                <h3>Completed</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="tasks_closed_list">
                {{#if visible.completed.length}}
                    <ul>{{#each visible.completed}}{{view Bee.TaskListView}}{{/each}}</ul>
                {{else}}
                    <p class="no_projects">None</p>
                {{/if}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
            <div class="col-header unassigned light-gradient">
                <h3>Unassigned</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="tasks_unassigned_list">
                {{#if visible.unassigned.length}}
                    <ul>{{#each visible.unassigned}}{{view Bee.TaskListView}}{{/each}}</ul>
                {{else}}
                    <p class="no_projects">None</p>
                {{/if}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Any insight will be much appreciated. I do know that the `Ember.Select` is the culprit, since when I replace it with a simple:

```
<select>
    {{#each projects.all}}
        <option value="{{_id}}">{{title}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

... it renders fine - however I need to use the `Ember.Select` so I can bind the value to the `project` property on the `TasksIndexController` - since I will use that as an observable for firing the `visible` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting projects.all to null up front. maybe ember select has an issue with the pojo default array on the class.

```
Bee.TasksIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  project: null
    content:
      tasks: 
        all: []
        inProgress: []
        completed: []
        unassgined: []
  projects: 
    all: null
    owned: []
    participating: []
  visible: (->
    ctrl = @
    # filter tasks here            
  ).property "project"



setupController: (ctrl) ->
    # get tasks
    Bee.Auth.send
        url: Bee.endpoint "/tasks"
    .done (tasks) -> 
        ctrl.set "tasks.all", tasks
    # get projects
    Bee.Auth.send
        url: Bee.endpoint "/projects"
    .done (projects) -> 
        ctrl.set "projects.owned", projects.owned
        ctrl.set "projects.participating", projects.participating
        ctrl.set "projects.all", projects.owned.concat projects.participating
```

Here's a simplified example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aletIyU/3/edit

Comment: Changing from `[]` to `null` didn't seem to make a difference, however after looking at the JSBin example I saw that it was using Ember 1.1.1 - so I updated my 1.0.0 build to the latest 1.1.2 and everything is working as I would expect it to. What a pain! Thanks for indirectly answering!

Comment: thanks @sp0rkyd0rky! this was driving me insane! I initially started with 1.1.1 but used canary builds for a while to test a few features. I recently came back to 1.1.1 and got this error.